# How do I sync two local file structures

Tags: bash, rsync

I have two large source trees. One of them has some out of date image files. I would like to automatically update all the old image files (png, jpg, gif) in one source tree with the up to date image files in the other source tree.

I am using Windows 7 but I have Cygwin installed. I have tried using rsync so far but with no success.

I was hoping I could do something like:

```
rsync -r *.png newSourceTree oldSourceTree
```

If there is some other way of achieving the same thing e.g. a Perl or Bash script, I'd be open to using that too.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
James.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
robocopy c:\source\ c:\destination\ *.png *.gif /s
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. I didn't even consider a Windows solution :/

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
rsync -av --include '*.png' --include '*/' --exclude '*' newSourceTree/ oldSourceTree/
```

A quick explanation:
You want to include png files, **include all directories** (so that it can recurse), then exclude everything else.  Include/Exclude are processed left to right, and default to including everything.

Answer (score 1):

[Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) is designed for exactly this sort of problem.  You can synchronize *all* the files using

```
unison oldTree newTree -force newer
```

If you want it to touch only image files, read the documentation.